# Order by with case statement fails only when using a parameter with error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list

Tags: sql-server, parameters, sql-order-by

I have a stored proc that consists of 3 queries joined by unions. This works. It currently has an order by value set like so:

```
    ORDER BY [CategoryTypeID], [SortOrder], [Name]
```

I want to make this dynamic so i tried using a case statement like this:

```
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sort = 0 then [CategoryTypeID] ELSE [SortOrder] end
```

However, when i do this sql complains that order by items must appear in the select list if the statement contains union... etc

However, if i change the above to avoid using the parameter:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 0 = 0 then [CategoryTypeID] ELSE [SortOrder] end
```

That works. Why is it unhappy when i use a parameter when that parameter is not actually being used in the order by? I even tried including the parameter in the select statements but it still gave me the same error.

I also tried doing case @sort when 1 etc but got the same results. And I did declare the parameter in my stored proc - @sort int = 0

This is MSSQL 2012 express

Edit - for additional clarity

```
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sort = 0 then [SortOrder] ELSE [CategoryTypeID] end
```

and

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sort = 0 then [CategoryTypeID] ELSE [CategoryTypeID] end
```

Both of those statements fail as well with a 'must appear in the select list' error. And i was not trying to use both of those statements at the same time. Just giving them as examples that the columns themselves dont appear to be an issue. It using the parameter that appears to be an issue, even though the paramter itself is not being selected or being sorted.

Comment: What is in your SELECT list though..? You need to actually _select_ this.

Comment: Because `ELSE` is never reached in the second case, so SQL Server acts as if it's not there. Try changing it to `WHEN 1 = 0`. Is `SortOrder` in your `SELECT` list? If not, why not?

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear - if you look at the first sample line of code, that works. Meaning, all 3 of those columns are in the select. So it doesn't matter if the else is never reached or not. I could swap which column is in the else and get the same results. For some reason it just doesn't like the paramter being used

Answer (score 4):

`CASE WHEN 0 = 0 then [CategoryTypeID] ELSE [SortOrder] end` is resolved at compile time and simplified to `CategoryTypeID`

You can do

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT [CategoryTypeID],
                [SortOrder]
         FROM   T1
         UNION
         SELECT [CategoryTypeID],
                [SortOrder]
         FROM   T2)
SELECT *
FROM   T
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN @sort = 0 THEN [CategoryTypeID]
            ELSE [SortOrder]
          END
```

Or

```
SELECT [CategoryTypeID],
       [SortOrder],
       CASE
         WHEN @sort = 0 THEN [CategoryTypeID]
         ELSE [SortOrder]
       END AS S
FROM   T1
UNION
SELECT [CategoryTypeID],
       [SortOrder],
       CASE
         WHEN @sort = 0 THEN [CategoryTypeID]
         ELSE [SortOrder]
       END AS S
FROM   T2
ORDER  BY S
```

Comment: What is the point of having two identical selects in a union?

Comment: @merk - They aren't identical because they are from different tables. If you had shown more of your original query it would have been possible to make it more relevant.

Comment: Ah sorry, i missed the T1 vs T2 bit.

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT SQL Server doesn't support statements like that, as the error indicates. You can use an IF construct to give different sorting based on a parameter.

```
IF @sort=0
    SELECT ... ORDER BY CategoryTypeID;
ELSE
    SELECT ... ORDER BY SortOrder;
```

Comment: You can comment on other people's answers once you have 50 rep. +1 as dividing into two queries may well give a better plan than a catch all query if indexes exist to support the sort. I disagree with the statement `whatever you do DO NOT USE WITH EVER` though. What are you basing that on?

Comment: Also, Martin Smiths version selects an extra column for the sake of sorting on it. The IF construct is more typing (copy/paste of course) but at least it doesn't select an extra column that you do not need. OTOH if you change/update the query you will have to retype (copy/paste of course) to the ELSE part.

Comment: The second version in my answer does just because they mentioned "I even tried including the parameter in the select statements" to show this was possible. Still waiting on the rationale for your avsersion to `WITH`

Comment: Personal experience. Absolute bad performance. Had colleagues unaware of this asking me why their query needed 11 (eleven) hours to run. They were using WITH. Changed to derived tables, query ran in mere seconds. That was on SQL Server 2008. The tables in the WITH clause are reevaluated each time they are needed in the query... it is a (table) expression, not a derived table.

Comment: derived tables and common table expressions are algebrised identically. If you got a different plan when switching from one to another there must have been something else going on (e.g. parameter sniffing)

Comment: Martin if you want to continue this discussion, please send me a mail so we can continue this discussion without going off-topic here. I work for the financial sector (asset management) and performance is a critical factor for the queries I write. I know from personal experience that using WITH is a no-no because of terrible query performance. If you want I can provide you with proof queries that illustrate the problems with WITH statement.

Comment: If you have a repro I'd be interested to see it. I have a contact email address in my profile.

Comment: I'm very interested in this side topic.  I prefer CTEs to derived tables for readability, and have not seen any performance problems.  Could you open a new thread for this?  Maybe TT could post his problem queries and then post his own solution?

Comment: It is hard to give examples from the field, I've already had a "use WITH coz it looks good" period and had to change it all because of extremely poor execution times. In financial sector performance is key and usually queries run on large data sets, not idealized examples running on Northwind. In this side-bar context I can only distill things and give you the conclusion I made a long time ago: Don't ever use WITH (unless maybe for recursive problems). I've burned my finger using WITH, and I'm never using it again.

Comment: The solution as you state is wagregg, at least for large datasets and complex (non-trivial) queries, is to use temporary tables. One might use derived tables, but for large data sets temporary tables offer better performance. Temporary tables can have PK's or indices on them to further boost performance. If you have small datasets, of course you will never see a performance difference. But try running it on tables with several million rows and non-trivial queries, and you will notice it. I've also had this problem with complex queries running on average-sized tables. So hard to illustrate here

Comment: @TT. - Thanks for sending the repro. Your initial comment mentioned derived tables vs CTE though and the repro code is for `#temp` table vs CTE in which case I agree when the CTE would be evaluated multiple times materialising it into a `#temp` table can sometimes be beneficial. A related connect item is [Provide a hint to force intermediate materialization of CTEs or derived tables](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables)

Comment: Please don't fear-monger about CTEs. Also I would rather maintain one version of a query, in general, than two. And that feeling is stronger the more complex the query gets.

Comment: Martin, the same optimization (hours vs minutes) exists when the query uses derived i/o temporary tables. It's just that for large data sets, temp tables generally perform better. I'm highlighting a clear performance flaw in the WITH construct as implemented in SQL Server 2008 and versions before (haven't tested 2012). I haven't ready-made proof because I've banned from our products, due to horrible experiences. I'll make some time to give clear examples and I'll start a blog then.

Comment: Tbh Martin, the TOP-trick is more of a hack than anything else. Interesting to know, though so thanks for the pointer.